# Spring OAuth2 Resource Server, creating a new user based on OAuth information

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have set up OAuth2 using google as the authorization server with my resource server (Spring) and I am able to access the API's on my server using OAuth2. Although I am not sure what would be the best way to register a user.

I can check to see if a user is already exists or not in the server and create it when they make an API request. But I am not sure if this was the way it was meant to be done. I am very new to OAuth2 just started learning how to implement them 2 days ago, therefore I would appreciate some feedback on the way to do it properly.

As shown below I am throwing an exception when the user cannot be found after getting user info for the token or if its saved in the database as an existing user.

```
private Authentication getAuthenticationToken(String accessToken) {
    Map<String, ?> userInfo = getUserInfo(accessToken);
    String id = (String) userInfo.get("sub");
    String email = (String) userInfo.get("email");
    Boolean email_verified = (Boolean) userInfo.get("email_verified");
    String given_name = (String) userInfo.get("given_name");
    String family_name = (String) userInfo.get("family_name");
    String name = (String) userInfo.get("name");
    String picture = (String) userInfo.get("picture");

    User user = userService.getUserByEmail(email);
    if (id == null)
    {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("User not found");
        //If possible replace this with API Response
    }
    else if(user == null)
    {
        throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("User not registered");
        //If possible forward request to registration page to create user with userinfo?
        //Or should i just create user everytime this happens?
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new GooglePrincipal(userService.getUserByEmail(email)), null, conversionUtils.getUserAuthority(user.getRoles()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a tricky area not often explained well.

I assume after login you are matching up the user's email from the Google token with your own database? This is quite a common technique.

Not sure I know what will work best for you, but my [write up](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/) may give you some ideas on options for identifying and managing users.